# Android Google Api for SpreadSheet

Tags: android, api, google-api, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out how to use Google Api for accessing/editing Google SpreadSheet.
I want to have a connection always with the same spreadsheet from many devices. I got examples using the AccountManager, but i should not use the user account. There is any good turorial?
Right now i've got the following..is that right?

AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        ArrayList googleAccounts = new ArrayList();

```
    // Just for the example, I am using the first google account returned.
    Account account = new Account("email@gmail.com", "com.google");

    // "wise" = Google Spreadheets
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> amf = accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "wise", null, this, null, null);

    try {
        Bundle authTokenBundle = amf.getResult();
        String authToken = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

        // do something with the token
        //InputStream response = sgc.getFeedAsStream(feedUrl, authToken, null, "2.1");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: I found a great example here: http://code.google.com/p/yetanothercoder/ hope this can help someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Required permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

**Choose needed outh token type from the table:**

http://code.google.com/intl/ja/apis/spreadsheets/faq_gdata.html#Authentication

Spreadsheets Data API   **wise**

**Code sample:**

```
public class OuthTokenActivity extends Activity {
String tag = "DEBUG";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    for (Account account : mAccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")) {
        mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, "wise", savedInstanceState,
                this, resultCallback, null);
    }
}

AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> resultCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
        try {
            Bundle result = future.getResult();
            String token = (String) result.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            String name = (String) result.get(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            Log.d(tag, String.format("name: %s, token: %s", name, token));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: thanks, but this requires that the user has got within his accounts the spreadsheet one. Imagine you have to commercialize the app and you want that the spreadsheet is your server...you can't ask to anyone to setup the account within his one. There isn't any way that can allow the "blind login" from the code?

Answer (score 1):

There is [an API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/?hl=es-ES) released now, available for java script, which could be run in your app. And they show how to integrate this into an Android app in a video [here](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/325022258).